# Dynamic SVG injection in svelte

Tags: html, svg, svelte, procedural-generation

I'm rendering some dynamically generated SVGs in a svelte app that are generated as strings and then put into individual `<svg>` tags:

```
<script lang="ts">
  import { IconGenerator } from "../icons/iconGenerator";

  let icons = [];
  for (let index = 0; index < 15; index++) {
    icons.push(IconGenerator.generate());
  }
</script>

<div>
  {#each icons as icon}
    <div>
      <svg viewBox="0 0 600 600" width="300" height="300">
        {@html icon}
      </svg>
    </div>
  {/each}
</div>
```

So far this works great, but I'd like to start using gradients which would be different per icon.

How can I define the gradient's ids and keep them scoped only to the icon they belong with and not have them be applied to the whole page?

I've looked into a few SVG injector libraries that handle making unique ids but they all seem to be made for non dynamic svgs available at a url not made on the fly from strings.

Comment: Wrap them in a [shadowDOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Using_shadow_DOM) Contrary to what almost al blogs tell you, you can set a shadowRoot on HTML elements, without using Custom Elements

Comment: Or just make all the ids globally unique

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A version using Shadow DOM via [use:action](https://svelte.dev/docs#template-syntax-element-directives-use-action), where the ids wouldn't interfere [REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/f33d549bad26444a860befe5cd9bddb7?version=3.48.0)

```
<script>
    let icons = [
        `<defs><linearGradient id="gradient" gradientTransform="rotate(90)">
      <stop offset="5%"  stop-color="gold" />
        <stop offset="95%" stop-color="red" />
    </linearGradient></defs>
    <circle cx="100" cy="100" r="100" fill="url(#gradient)"/>`,

        `<defs><linearGradient id="gradient" x1="0" x2="0" y1="0" y2="1">
        <stop offset="0%" stop-color="teal"/>
        <stop offset="50%" stop-color="darkblue" stop-opacity="50"/>
        <stop offset="100%" stop-color="blue"/>
    </linearGradient></defs>
    <rect id="rect" width="200" height="200" rx="15" fill="url(#gradient)"/>`
    ]

    function shadow(node) {
        const shadowRoot = node.attachShadow({mode: 'open'})
        const children = Array.from(node.children)
        children.forEach(child => shadowRoot.appendChild(child))
    }
</script>

<div>
    {#each icons as icon, index}
    <div class="shadow-host" use:shadow>
        <svg viewBox="-50 -50 300 300" width="200" height="200" style="display:block;">
            {@html icon}
        </svg>
    </div>
    {/each}
</div>

<style>
    .shadow-host {
        border: 2px solid lightgrey;
    }
</style>
```